# populate an ArrayCollection dynamically flex

Tags: json, actionscript-3, apache-flex, arraycollection

I'm trying to populate an `ArrayCollection` with a `json data` in order to use it as a `dataprovider` for a `LineChart`.
I tried to use the following code however it wouldn't work.

```
jsonData= (com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.decode(dataLoader.data));

for (var i:int=0; i<10; i++){
        frame.addItem({ date_time:((jsonData[i].date_time).toString()) , glucose:((jsonData[i].content).glucose)}); }
```

Can anyone please help me?
Thanks.

Comment: What's not working? What's happening that shouldn't be? It's considered poor quality to not explain these things at the outset.

Comment: @NealDavis, Thank you for your reply and sorry for the poor quality.
what is not working is that I couldn't get the two objects (date_time and glucose) in the ArrayCollection to obtain data dynamically from the json array. it only works if the data is static but I need it to be dynamically put into the ArrayCollection since the json data is always changing.

Comment: Can you post the json data that you are decoding?

Comment: @RobinvandenBogaard, this is the part that I need from an object of my json data Array.

  {
   
    "content": {
      "temp": 37,
      "glucose": 135,
      "systolic": 98,
      "diastolic": 64,
      "pulse": 68,
      "id": "11011416"
    },
    "micVerif": true,
    "codr": "4/5",
    "size": 95,
    "date_time": "2016-09-15T19:41:30.222228Z",
....
},

Comment: @RobinvandenBogaard, the json data is obtained via an URLLoader which means it's always changing and I can read it just fine. However, what I couldn't do is to populate the ArrayCollection with it.
so I can set it as a dataprovier for my chart and then to set its objects for "mychart.yfield= glucose" and "mychart.xfield=date_time" this is why I need to populate it dynamically.
and yes this json object is an array and the "..." means more variables, what I posted previously is just a small part of an object among the json array.

Comment: Ok, can you include the line graph code?

Comment: @RobinvandenBogaard, here it is: var localSeries:LineSeries = new LineSeries();
 localSeries.dataProvider = frame;
 localSeries.yField = "glucose";
 localSeries.xField = "date_time";
 localSeries.displayName = "Glucose Level";
 var currentSeries:Array = myChart.series;
 currentSeries.push(localSeries);
 myChart.series = currentSeries;
 var hAxis:DateTimeAxis = new DateTimeAxis();
 hAxis.parseFunction = createDate;
 myChart.horizontalAxis = hAxis;
 }

Answer (score 0):

This test application works. It uses a stripped down version of your json data. But processes it the same. I also use a different JSON decoder.

The only thing I can think of is that your createDate function is faulty. I used a simple version to demonstrate everything should work as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.charts.DateTimeAxis;
            import mx.charts.series.LineSeries;
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            [Bindable]
            private var frame:ArrayCollection;

            protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
                frame = new ArrayCollection();

                var data:String = '[{ "content": { "glucose": 135 }, "date_time": "2016,09,15"},' +
                    '{ "content": { "glucose": 55 }, "date_time": "2016,09,16"},' +
                    '{ "content": { "glucose": 13 }, "date_time": "2016,09,17"},' +
                    '{ "content": { "glucose": 70 }, "date_time": "2016,09,18"}]';

                var jsonData:Object = JSON.parse(data);

                for each (var item:Object in jsonData) {
                    frame.addItem({ date_time:((item.date_time).toString()) , glucose:(item.content.glucose)});
                }

                var localSeries:LineSeries = new LineSeries(); 
                localSeries.dataProvider = frame; 
                localSeries.yField = "glucose"; 
                localSeries.xField = "date_time"; 
                localSeries.displayName = "Glucose Level"; 

                var currentSeries:Array = myChart.series; 
                currentSeries.push(localSeries); 
                myChart.series = currentSeries; 

                var hAxis:DateTimeAxis = new DateTimeAxis(); 
                hAxis.parseFunction = createDate; 
                myChart.horizontalAxis = hAxis;
            }

            public function createDate(s:String):Date {
                // Get an array of Strings from the 
                // comma-separated String passed in.
                var a:Array = s.split(",");

                // Trace out year, month, and day values.
                trace("y:" + a[0]);
                trace("m:" + a[1]);
                trace("d:" + a[2]);

                // To create a Date object, you pass "YYYY,MM,DD", 
                // where MM is zero-based, to the Date() constructor.
                var newDate:Date = new Date(a[0],a[1]-1,a[2]);
                return newDate;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:LineChart id="myChart" />

</s:WindowedApplication>
```